# How can we achive the replica of databases for SQL SERVER?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007, database-migration, vb6-migration

I have been working in VB6 to VB.NET migration project.In VB6 project they have individual databases(access db .mdb) for every user now we made that to **Centralized database** SQL SERVER.In VB6 the individual db is a replica DB and has a Master-db which located some where. Now we need to do this process for SQL SERVER also.How can we achieve this for Centralized database like SQL Server?This should work for each and every user also.

Can anybody help regarding this or share any links ?

Comment: What reasons are there for the individual databases? Connectivity? Confidentiality?

Comment: Having migrated to a central SQL Server, this should have negated any further need for individual copies of database files which are then merged afterwards (as long as user's can access the SQL server at all times) which I'm guessing they should be able to as a `.net app` seems an awful waste of time if it is only used offline by individuals??

Answer (score 1):

SQL Database is used as a single .mdf file (.log file is also with it so 2 files)
So the simple concept for one user per one file is not suitable (however it can be
implemented i.e. each user will have its SQL database working separately on his computer)

You will then implement the logic to update the main database placed at some server
on detecting the idle time of the machine or some other suitable time

you can also use

Comment: According the Old App we need to sync the local.mdb with the master.mdb in online .I have searched alot to implement this in SQL Server.I have seen the same scenario in MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreplication/thread/aeda1871-e2f4-4202-aea0-27f89a393566. I think I need to go for Merge replication. Am I right regarding choosing the replication type?

Comment: @JaiGanesh If you are planning with going for a seperate SQL Server instance on each user's machine, then yes `Merge Replication` is what you are going to need. However I still think this approach is flawed.